# What's the difference between InputEndpoints -> inputEndpoint and Endpoints -> inputEndpoint (azure web role)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

This is almost the default settings when creating a cloud project in visual studio. I have added the `<InputEndpoints>` element. I know that the

```
<Endpoints>
<InputEndpoint>
```

is for how external users will reach my application but what is the

```
<InputEndpoints>
<InputEndpoint>
```

for?

```
<WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<InputEndpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
</InputEndpoints>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InternalEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="80" />
</Endpoints>
```

Thanks

EDIT:
This is [my source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#InstanceInputEndpoint).

Answer (score 0):

`<InputEndpoints>` is not part of the [WebRole schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx). All of your endpoints (input/internal) belong under the `<Endpoints>` element.